# Calling Graph APIs from Web APIs that have Kerberos authentication

Tags: azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks, webapi

I'm trying to figure out which is the ouath2 scenario of my application and how to call Graph APIs in the behalf of a user with SSO.

My app is composed like this:

angular js (anonimous) -> .NET REST Web APIs (Kerberos)

so I have an anonimous client that calls Web APIs using Kerberos as authentication,
and what I need to do is to call Azure to get a oauth2 token from inside those Web APIs.

the idea is to use the context given by Kerberos to impersonate the user and use the 
`var auth = app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).ExecuteAsync()` 
method of the MSAL Library.

Is this the correct approach? Or should I change the  flow?

I was also reading that `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` would deadlock if not called in the UI Thread, being this a simple Web API project, could this happens in anyway?

Comment: But the request for a token originating from your API will no longer be in the user's but your app's security context, unless your API also does KCD. Isn't that your problem (as well)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I'm totally new about this topic... What is KCD? At the moment, using impersonate,  I'm able to call EWS apis with the user context, setting defaultCredentials = true.  I need to call Graph instead of EWS the same way, but I need a OAuth2 token first

Comment: If your AAD is federated to an on-premises issuer (e.g. ADFS) then you MIGHT be able to use AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth. MSAL will then issue a WS-Trust call to ADFS with the users Kerberos token, get a SAML token and exchange it for a JWT with AAD. You will need to make sure that your call to MSAL is running in the users security context. Never tried it from a web app so can't speak from experience. Note that if your AAD is NOT federated, this will not work.

Comment: thanks @Marc unfortunately the users cannot be federated :(
There is only Passthrough authentication and SSO enabled, is there a way to use it?

I was looking at the OnBehalfOf method, but I need a JWT token, and I only have Kerberos...is there a way to Exchange this Kerberos token with something else?

Comment: You can use the OBO (extension) flow to exchange eitehr a SAML or JWT token but not a Kerberos token. In PTA/SSO users would be on AAD joined machines most likely so MSAL integrated would work but in your case the API is running on another machine altogether. Move the API to Azure App Services and use EasyAuth to get almost the same effect as on-premises kerberos (your client apps will need to get a token).

Comment: Thanks again for the support, it seems I found a way finally. I used ADAL and the AquireTokenAsync method passing and empty instance of UserCredential. It seems that with ADAL I can use the Kerberos and SSO without the need of having federated users! I hope that it doesn't deprecate in the future to force MSAL usage

Comment: That's interesting. I am familiar with ADAL acquiring token in such a way by calling WSTrust/Kerberos endpoint of the federation server and then exchanging the returned SAML for a JWT token with AAD. Any chance you could have a look at a Fiddler trace to see how ADAL does it in your case. Since your API is running with its own security principal I cannot imagine how WS-Trust resolves the Kerberos ticket. MSAL has AcauireTokenByWindowsAuth (something like that).